# How to separate name and surname

Tags: c#, database, split

I have code name and surname put into same    string with coma in the middle ,as "JohnSmith"

I need to insert into database to separate

Can you show me how to code that please.

Thanks

vijay

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow :) Tip: don't ask "give me code", rather ask "how to do it?". Also see http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @BalusC: I prefer to receive answers that describe how to do something in code (even if it's VBScript :) ). Does that make me a lazy idiot?

Comment: @Simon: No. You just get as much effort back as you evidently put in. Asking "give me code" is just plain rude.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably your asking how to split up a single string where the names are seperated by a comma `','`

If that's the case, you can split a string using the `Split(char x)` method.
Then you can use each part what ever way you want.

```
string x = "John,Smith";

string [] parts = x.Split(',');


if(parts.Length == 2)
{
   string firstName = parts[0];
   string secondName = parts[1];
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: -1 for actually responding with code to "Can you give me code for that."

Comment: @Eoin, I have some code I need you to write asap. Sending it now.

Comment: @Eoin, jumping in and writing code in my opinion is not the best way to let the OP learn. Talk them through the solution and let them write it themselves.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think @Preet should have helped the OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

Vijay, how about at least trying to google stuff like this by yourself? As in "C# split string"? Hundreds of decent results come up. Heck, there are tons of these examples on SO as well.

Other people can't do your work for you, so how about actually putting in some effort into learning process instead of relying on others to do mundane things for you?

Comment: +1. Though I guess if others want to do the work for the lazy-inclined, who are we to argue? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in most cases, but in a production environment the edge cases kill you. I like the string.split answer, but the incredible variation in how names are formated means more thinking and more code.